# How to alias external module path when in ssr?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, server-side-rendering, prerender

https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals/issues/66

There's a problem for me to do SSR building, it's our framework export alias module, and use `resolve.alias` to alias the module , like React, we use

```
import React from 'bar/lib/sdk/react';

// not use
import React from 'react';

// bar/lib/sdk/react/index.d.ts not have index.js
// the `bar` is alias `lib/sdk/react` with `bar/node_modules/react`
```

so now, I only add bar/lib/sdk/react into whiteList, but it's unconscionable to bundle all React library.

How could I solve the problem?

In other words, I config the `resolve.alias = { 'bar/sdk/react': dirname(join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules', 'react')) }` both in client and server webpackConfig.

I write in the project like

```
import React from 'bar/sdk/react';
```

output in server dist bundle is 'bar/sdk/react' not use alias '/node_modules/_react@16.8.6@react'

so run in server, it's crash.

Comment: If I understood your problem, please  take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias

Comment: not module alias, I want to the module path transform `bar/lib/sdk/react` into `bar/node_modules/react`, because the `bar/lib/sdk/react` just export `React` use `bar` lib node_moudles.